# Android Volley Rails: NoMethodError (undefined method `+@' for "":String)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, android-volley, nomethoderror

I have the Volley method within my android app to access and create an event entry in the rails MySQL database:

```
                   JsonObjectRequest createEventGetID = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://" + Global.getFeastOnline() + "/createEvent",
                            new JSONObject(jsonParams),
                            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    params.put("user_id", settings.getString("userID","0"));
                                    params.put("campaign_id", "-1");
                                    params.put("location_id", "-1");
                                    params.put("event_active", event.getAlarmActive().toString());
                                    params.put("event_removed", "0");
                                    params.put("event_time", event.getAlarmTimeString());
                                    params.put("event_days", Base64.encodeToString(buff, Base64.DEFAULT)); 
                                    params.put("event_tone", event.getAlarmTonePath());
                                    params.put("event_vibrate", event.getVibrate().toString());
                                    params.put("event_name", event.getAlarmName());
                                    params.put("event_date", event.getAlarmDateString());

                                    return params;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    // Parse the JSON:
                                    try {
                                        // Returning JSON, tag:
                                        JSONArray newEventID = response.getJSONArray("new_event_server_id");

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newEventID.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        // PARSE THE REST

                                        //Log.v("New Event ID", "The new event id is " + userId);

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    // error
                                    Log.d("Create Events Error", error.toString());
                                }
                            }
                    );
                    requestQueue.add(createEventGetID);
```

Volley has no problem sending as they are all strings in the POST request. The createEvent method in rails is:

```
def createEvent 

        createEvent = "INSERT INTO events(
                                      event_creator_id
                                    , campaign_id
                                    , location_id
                                    , event_active
                                    , event_removed
                                    , event_time
                                    , event_days
                                    , event_tone
                                    , event_vibrate
                                    , event_name
                                    , event_date
                                    , created_at
                                    , updated_at                                    
                       ) VALUES (" 
                               + params[:user_id].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:campaign_id].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:location_id].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:event_active].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:event_removed].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:event_time].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:event_days].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:event_tone].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:event_vibrate].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:event_name].to_s + "," 
                               + params[:event_date].to_s + "," 
                                + "NOW(),NOW()"
                               + ")"


        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(createEvent)

    end
```

and route as:

```
  match '/createEvent', to: "requests#createEvent", via: 'post'
```

When testing the volley action, the rails command lines throws error as:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `+@' for "":String):
  app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:522:in `createEvent'
```

on line: `+ params[:user_id].to_s + ","` of the `createEvent` method.

I have tried everything including removing all inserted values form the `createEvent` method aside from a hard-coded "0", yet the error persists.

How can this be alleviated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, that is not a good design of controller, not to say your code is not secure (waiting for an SQL injection to happen).

Just use ActiveRecord, create Event model (put this into app/models/event.rb):

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Then edit your controller:

```
def createEvent 
  Event.create!(event_creator_id: params[:user_id], campaign_id: params[:campaign_id], ...) # add all your parameters
  head :no_content
end
```

On your initial question: you have to put '+' signs on the same line with previous string, so you will have something like:

```
"...) VALUES (" + params[:user_id].to_s + "," + # plus is at the end of line, not the beginning
params[:campaign_id].to_s + "," +
# ... etc.
```

Comment: Thank you, can you see my other question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776770/rails-post-route-doesnt-see-parameters